# Help with jQuery selector for select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the `.change()` event I want to store the value of an attribute of the currently selected option. Please help me finish the below code.

```
$("#someid").change(function() {
    var myNumber;
});
```

Comment: @patrick, any one, lets make one up. "myAttr".

Comment: The reason I had asked was that some attributes are easily accessible as a property. The ID for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want need it outside the handler, you'll need to declare the variable outside.

```
var myNumber;

$("#someid").change(function() {
    myNumber = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].getAttribute('myAttr');
    // or
    myNumber = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('myAttr');
});
```

If you only need it inside, then declare the variable inside.

Comment: @nick, still i can't understand why you need myNumber variable ? :) Patrick's answer will help you.